# Hint for $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\cos\frac{1}{i}}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\cos\frac{1}{i}}}$$

thanks.

Comment: Using `\prod` will render the formula much better than `\Pi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n ^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\cos[1/(n+1)]} = 1$$

Comment: many thanks @RRL but why this two test is equal?

Comment: Cauchy's second limit theorem

Answer (score 2):

Apply $\ln$ to get

$$\tag 1\frac{1}{n}\left (\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln [1/\cos (1/k)].\right)$$

Now $\ln [1/\cos (1/k)] \to 0$ as $k\to \infty.$ Therefore $(1),$ which are the Cesaro means of these terms, also converge to $0.$ Hence the limit of the original expression is $1.$